# Hiding mfc horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c++, mfc

I would like to hide a horizontal scrollbar. I can already hide the vertical using:

```
ShowScrollBar(false);
```

If I use this on the horizontal scrollbar then I get relict window that does not draw properly. My goal is for the scrollbar to dissapear permanently, so if there is a way to destroy it then that would be okay.

The scrollbar was manually added to a class which inherits CWnd called CFolderFrame, the class I want to change inherits from CFolderFrame and CRichEditView. I can not change CFolderFrame since I am working with old code and CFolderFrame gets inherited by other things.

Comment: You didn't specify whether this is on some textbox control or on an MFC View

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic edited my question hope it is better now

Answer (score 0):

Very simple just use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4410/Hide-scrollbars-from-a-CListCtrl  it will do give call to m_list1.HideScrollBars(LCSB_CLIENTDATA, SB_VERT); and you on fly :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly I can not add this project, it is a very large and old programme making a change like that would require an endless amount of testing. What I need is to make a CScrollBar invisible or remove it from a CWnd.